# Using querystring module with Node.js http module

Tags: node.js, query-string

So I have this:

```
const server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    const url = req.url;
    const q = qs.parse(url);

    console.log('querystring =>',q);

    if(q.path){
      fs.createReadStream(q.path).pipe(res);
    }
    else {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end(JSON.stringify({error: 'no path or bundle.'}))
    }

});
```

I get these logged for `'querystring'`:

```
querystring => { '/suman_testing?data': '{"path":"/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman/test/src/dev/browser/test-file.html"}' }
querystring => { '/favicon.ico': '' }
```

uhh, so what am I supposed to do? I would have expected that the default would be to parse everything after the `?` character.

Is the right way to do this to split the string by the `?` character and parse everything after that?

Answer (score 0):

This was a little less straightforward than I expected, this is how I got it working:

```
const url = require('url');

let httpServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    const {query} = url.parse(req.url, true);
    // query is now a plain JS key/value object, parsed from query string
});
```